# A harder tournament to schedule

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Let us suppose that I have $n$ students in my class, and I break them up into $k$ groups per week. Let's also suppose that I want to repeat this each week, except that I don't want any student to work with any other student more than once.
>
> For how many weeks can this continue?

This is an extension of some of the classic tournament-scheduling questions, and it wouldn't surprise me if there were an equally elementary approach. But I haven't found it yet. And since I haven't found it yet, I haven't come across the divisibility relationships that would facilitate a 'nice' answer, other than $k \mid n$.

Comment: This isn't a hint since I don't know the answer but perhaps you might find it useful. For a given person, they will meet $\frac{n}{k}-1$ new people each week. So if $m$ is the number of weeks this continues, then certainly we must have $m(\frac{n}{k}-1) < n$. Could it ever be this large?

Comment: Is it assumed that the groups must be equal-sized?

Answer (score 7):

This is the [Social Golfer Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html); no general solution is known. Some data can be found [here](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sello/golf.html), and there is a [Wolfram Social Golfer Problem Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/) where you can find a useful links and information. [Kirkman’s Schoolgirl Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem) is a special case that is quite well known.