Number of combinations of distinct groups
Suppose you have a class of $M\cdot N$ students and want to split them in groups of $N$, to complete an activity, e.g divide a class of 21 in $M=7$ groups of $N=3$.
How many activities can you plan so that every activity has groups of students that were never paired in a previous activity?
Note that I am interested in the number of activities, not the different way in which I can split the students.
E.g. with 6 students and groups of 3 I cannot do more than 1 activity: grouping ABC and DEF for the first activity there is no way to combine students for the second activity so that none met any other group mate. With 9 students and groups of 3 there are 4 activities.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design

Not answering your question but correct one of your claims: with nine students you can do four activities.

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem & https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/ There are simple solutions when M=N is a prime or prime power. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100315/how-many-rounds-would-it-take-to-get-each-pair-on-the-same-team-at-least-once-n/4176954#comment8520199_4100315

@jetfiRex how? abc def ghi - adg beh cfi -what are the other two?

@andream. aei bfg cdh, and afh bdi ceg.

The  $9$ students, groups of $3$, has a picture. $$\matrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&f\cr g&h&i\cr}$$ Horizontal: $abc,def,ghi$. Vertical: $adg,beh,cfi$. (Broken) diagonal: $aei,bfg,cdh$. Other (broken) diagonal: $ceg,bdi,afh$.

This appears to be an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200989/

@MikeEarnest Except that this question has a specific example, which has a known solution, given below.

The answer is ten. In Mathematical Recreations and Essays (Dover Math Games & Puzzles) book Page 280, you can have the construction. I copy from the book and paste it here:
Day 1: (1, 4, 10). (8, 11, 17). (15, 18, 3). (2, 6, 7). (9, 13, 14). (16, 20.21). (5, 12, 19).
Day 2~7: All indices of Day 1, but $+1$, $+2$, to $+6$ then modulo $21$.
Day 8: (1, 3, 11). (4, 6, 14). (7, 9, 17). (10, 12, 20). (13, 15, 2). (16, 18, 5). (19, 21, 8).
Day 9~10: All indices of Day 8, but $+1$ and $+2$ then modulo $21$.
More of the related articles can be found here:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KirkmanTripleSystem.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Steiner_triple_systems
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem
